# Combinations by changing 3 or more places in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, product, python-itertools

The code below takes a string, then in `p =` there is a mapping for every index that can be changed and with what characters. For example `d1` is at`p[0]`, so the character `a` (at `string[0]`) can be replaced by `d` or `1`. The number of characters that have to change at a time is limited to the number 3.

```
from itertools import combinations, product

string = "abc123" 

p = ["d1", "c3", "", "", "0", "56"]

d = {idx: (v if string[idx] in v else string[idx]+v) for idx, v in enumerate(p)} 

all_of_em = (''.join(whatever) for whatever in product(*d.values()))

fewer = [w for w in all_of_em if sum(a != b for a, b in zip(w, string)) == 3]

with open("list.txt","w") as f: 
    for w in fewer: 
        f.write(w+"\n")
```

As a result of the above code, we find all possible combinations if we change 3 places in a string with the specified alternative characters in `p`.

```
acc105
acc106
a3c105
a3c106
dbc105
dbc106
dcc125
dcc126
dcc103
d3c125
d3c126
d3c103
1bc105
1bc106
1cc125
1cc126
1cc103
13c125
13c126
13c103
```

The goal is to print the results faster, for example these lines should be changed I think:

```
with open("list.txt","w") as f: 
    for w in fewer: 
        f.write(w+"\n")
```

So the output will be saved as `python3 py.py >> list.txt`

Will enjoy to learn from your solution.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Tomerikoo the code is super slow, after 15000 combinations I can't get it working even though I have other scripts that generate millions of combinations without a problem, so as I mentioned the goal is to make it faster.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you're trying to do.   The variable `p` makes no sense to me.

Comment: @FrankYellin each " " is the place in a string, for example a string abc has p = ["", "", ""] value so in order to change first character we can do this way  p = ["123bc", "", ""]

Comment: I'm sorry.  I still don't understand. What you're doing is clear to you, but I don't think it's clear to anyone else.   Where does "123bc" come from?

Comment: I think the OP, has an input string `abc123`, and the `p` contains a mapping for every index in the input string to possible alternatives. So `d1` (at `p[0]`) means that `a` (`string[0]`)  can be replaced by `d` and `1`.  This goes for all indices (`b` maps to `c` or `3`, etc....Now he wants to change 3 indices from `abc123`, with the corresponding values in `p`. Then he generalizes to making all possible replacement options and the final question is to do it faster.

Comment: @FrankYellin 123bc is a just random characters that we can change in a position 0 of a string, it's can be anything

Comment: @Thymen exactly right

Comment: You don't need `fewer` at all... It's an unnecessary list in memory. Just loop the `all_of_em` and write directly to the file... I'm sure this will cut down some runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is based on a brute force approach. You are generating all possible alternative strings and then filtering out the ones that do not meet the criteria of only 3 changes. A better approach would be to look only at those combinations that will meet the criteria. I will ignore the part of saving to a file, since it will be the same for both solutions. A faster solution would be:

```
def change_string(input_string, mapping, replace=3):
    input_string = list(input_string)

    to_replace = dict()
    for idx, replacement in enumerate(mapping):
        if not replacement: continue

        to_replace[idx] = replacement
        if input_string[idx] in replacement:
            to_replace[idx] = [char for char in replacement if char != mapping[idx]]

    for indices in combinations(to_replace, r=replace):
        for chars in product(*[to_replace[index] for index in indices]):
            temp = input_string[:]
            for index, char in zip(indices, chars):
                temp[index] = char
            yield ''.join(temp)
```

#### Explanation

I change the input string to a list, so I can do the replacement faster, since lists are mutable and strings are not.

Then I filter the mapping (`p`) to represent only indices that are going to be changed. This removes all empty strings and provides me with the indices that I have to look at.

```
to_replace = dict()
    for idx, replacement in enumerate(mapping):
        if not replacement: continue

        to_replace[idx] = replacement
        if input_string[idx] in replacement:
            to_replace[idx] = [char for char in replacement if char != mapping[idx]]
```

Note: I also make sure that the values in mapping are unequal to the original string values, which might not be what you want.

Then I create all possible combinations of indices with the required length (replace=3).

```
for indices in combinations(to_replace, r=replace):
```

Using your example this will contain the following group of indices:

```
(0, 1, 4)
(0, 1, 5)
(0, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 5)
```

Then I create all possible `character` combinations from those indices:

```
for chars in product(*[to_replace[index] for index in indices]):
```

For example with indices `(0, 1, 4)` or the values `('d1', 'c3', '0')`:

```
('d', 'c', '0')
('d', '3', '0')
('1', 'c', '0')
('1', '3', '0')
```

Are all the character combinations produced.

Then I create a copy of the input string (note it is a list, so we can perform fast replacements) and replace the characters at the correct indices.

### Comparison

- Your function

```
def OP(input_string, replace=3):
    p = ["d1", "c3", "", "", "0", "56"]
    d = {idx: (v if input_string[idx] in v else input_string[idx] + v) for idx, v in enumerate(p)}
    all_of_em = (''.join(whatever) for whatever in product(*d.values()))
    fewer = [w for w in all_of_em if sum(a != b for a, b in zip(w, input_string)) == replace]
    return fewer
```

#### Replace is 3

```
print(timeit.timeit("OP('abc123')", setup="from __main__ import OP", number=100_000))
# 5.6281933 seconds

print(timeit.timeit("list(change_string('abc123', ['d1', 'c3', '', '', '0', '56']))",
                    setup="from __main__ import change_string", number=100_000))
# 1.3682368 seconds
```

Which is about 3 times as fast, now the interesting part is to see what happens if we increase the replace value to 4

#### Replace is 4

```
print(timeit.timeit("OP('abc123', replace=4)", setup="from __main__ import OP", number=100_000))
# 5.5450302 seconds

print(timeit.timeit("list(change_string('abc123', ['d1', 'c3', '', '', '0', '56'], replace=4))",
                    setup="from __main__ import change_string", number=100_000))
# 0.6179974 seconds
```

A whooping 9 times faster, since my solution only has to check a few combinations.

Similar increase can be seen with using replace is `2` or `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator function will avoid creation and manipulation of large lists in memory.  You can write it to the file as a single block of text using join.

```
def replace(S,R,N):
    if not N: yield S; return
    for i,chars in enumerate(R[:(1-N) or None]):
        for c in chars:
            yield from (S[:i]+c+s for s in replace(S[i+1:],R[i+1:],N-1))
            
def writeReplace(S,R,N):
    with open("list.txt","w") as f: 
        f.write("\n".join(replace(S,R,3)))

S = "abc123" 
R = ["d1", "c3", "", "", "0", "56"]
writeReplace(S,R,3)

dcc103
dcc125
dcc126
d3c103
d3c125
d3c126
dbc105
dbc106
1cc103
1cc125
1cc126
13c103
13c125
13c126
1bc105
1bc106
acc105
acc106
a3c105
a3c106
```

This is roughly 2.5x faster.

Comment: it doesn't find all possible combinations

Comment: Which one didn't it find?  I got the same 20 values as your example, albeit not in the same order.